# .Net 6 Web Api Swagger Versioning problem

Tags: swagger, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

As the title suggests, i have a .net 6 web api that I'm trying to add versioning to but swagger (swashbuckle) does not seem to understand whats going on.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(setup =>
{
    setup.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    setup.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    setup.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"v1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v2/swagger.json", $"v2");
});

app.Run();

void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore();
        
    services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
    {
        options.ReportApiVersions = true;
        options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = false;
        options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
    });
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

I have annotated my controllers like so:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase

[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v2/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
```

The swagger document that is generated looks like this:

[image]

And if i select v2 from the drop down, I get this:

[image]

Nuget packages and versions installed are:

[image]

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Besides passing the configuration here:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V1", Version = "v1" });
     c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V2", Version = "v2" });
});
```

According to [the docs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/swashbuckle.aspnetcore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents) you have to specify the GroupName of the controller:

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v2/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
```

Also, the docs show ways to customize and add conventions.

Answer (score 2):

This article seems to have covered all the aspect what you are looking for.
Please have a look.
https://referbruv.com/blog/integrating-aspnet-core-api-versions-with-swagger-ui/

Comment: right on the money, saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the swagger documents themselves, not just the UI for them. In your `AddSwaggerGen` method, add something like:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Version = "v1", Title = "My API" });
    c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Version = "v2", Title = "My API" });
});
```

Comment: I've made this change, however all the endpoints v1 and v2 appear in both api version definitions when i change them in the drop downs. I'm expecting to only see the ones that have [ApiVersion("1.0")] to appear in the v1 swagger

Comment: @JsonStatham I believe decorating the action results with [MapToApiVersion("1")] and [MapToApiVersion("2")] is necessary. The [ApiVersion] attribute only designates which versions apply at the controller level. [MapToApiVersion] gives you the flexibility to map action results to multiple different versions within the same controller. So, you could opt to decorate the controller with both [ApiVersion("1")] and [ApiVersion("2")], then decorate actionresults Listv1 with [MapToApiVersion("1")] and Listv2 with [MapToApiVersion("2")]. Also, nice username ;)

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new version of API make sure to add it to AddSwaggerGen Method as below

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V1", Version = "v1.0" , Description = "Version 1 Description "});
    c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V2", Version = "v2.0" , Description = "Version 2 Description "});
    c.SwaggerDoc("v3", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V3", Version = "v3.0", Description = "Version 3 Description " });
});
```